# how to use ES6 features in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ecmascript-6

My one website is into requirement gathering stage. I know that JavaScript new version ES6 is introduced.

On googling, I found some good tools to work with ES6 like:-

- Bable
- Traceur

Is there any Nuget package available or any alternate that will convert ES6 to ES5 parallely.

or How do I get started with ES6 in ASP.Net MVC site.

I am using VS 2015 & ASP.Net(4.5.2)

Comment: I supposed that asp.net is server-side framework, but js is usually client-side (except for node.js which is not the case here), am I missing something?

Comment: Even Angular is js framework, but we download Angular package using Nuget

Comment: can you use angular from asp.net (C# I assume) code? not from html/js which is generated, but from C#?

Comment: http://reactjs.net/guides/es6.html

Comment: was about to post the same question, shame there is no answer on SO on 'how to implement babel on an MVC project?' @Kgn-web did you find a solution? if so, please share :)

Comment: You could use TypeScript and have it compile to ES5

Answer (score 0):

You can try Webpack with visual Studio [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner) is a useful package. Just dont forget you require the Babel module.